# Validación no verifica existencia de un usuario en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas noches he intentado que me valide los 2 campos para el login pero no lo hace, con cualquier dato me dice que es exitoso cuando en la base de datos no existe ningún registros que yo pongo en el login.

Conexión BD

```
<?php 
    function Conectarse ()
    {
    $Conexion=new MySQLi ("localhost","Futboldh","Clave123","futbol_time");
    if ($Conexion->connect_errno)
        echo "Problemas en la Conexion" .$Conexion->connect_error;
    else
        return $Conexion;
    }
?>
```

Código del Login

```
<?php 

include("Conexion.php");

$objConexion = Conectarse ();

$usuario = $_POST ['usuario'];
$clave = $_POST ['password'];


if (!empty($usuario)|| !empty($clave)){

$iniciarsesion = "SELECT * FROM tbl_login_registro WHERE Correo_electronico = '$usuario' AND Contraseña = '$clave'";

$resultado = $objConexion -> query($iniciarsesion);

echo "Inicio";
}

else
{
    echo "No se pudo iniciar sesión";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola si, es que estaba haciendo una prueba y puse los datos directos pero hay va es: $usuario, $clave, ya esta editado el código en la pregunta, lo siento soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Ya lo corregi, tienes idea de que sucede?

Comment: si que ambos existan en la tabla

Answer (score 1):

A simple vista por que en tu if lo que estas validando es que $usuario y $contraseña no vengan vacíos.
Lo que deberías de validad es $usuario y $contraseña con tus datos que traes en $iniciarsesion.

Comment: Hola Jaime valide $iniciarsesion con un if !empty y aun no valida los registros contra la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

- Tu código no tiene alguna parte donde busque validar la existencia del registro como tal, es decir hace la consulta solo cuando los valores están presentes, pero eso no es indicio de que el registro exista (*eso es tema aparte*)
- Debes validar tanto si la variable esta definida como si no esta vacia
- Como deseas saber si el registro existe o no, entonces no debes usar el operador || por que podría ejecutar la consulta con un valor faltante y dentro de la query estás solicitando ambos
- Cuando se trata de verificar la existencia de un registro, lo mejor es hacer un conteo de las filas que existan asociadas a esos valores
- Usemos a `num_rows` para leer el número que devolvió esa consulta
- Con un condicional interno debes verificar:

  - Si es mayor a 0 entonces el registro ya existe
  - Sino entonces el registro si existe

    ```
      include("Conexion.php");

      $objConexion = Conectarse();

      $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
      $clave   = $_POST['password'];


      if (isset($usuario) && !empty($usuario) && isset($clave) && !empty($clave)) {

          $iniciarsesion = $objConexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM tbl_login_registro 
                              WHERE Correo_electronico = '".$usuario."' 
                              AND Contraseña = '".$clave."' 
                          ");

          $resultado = $iniciarsesion->num_rows;

          if ($resultado > 0) {
              echo 'El usuario si existe';
          } else {
              echo 'El usuario no existe';
          }
      } else {
          echo "No se pudo iniciar sesión verifica los valores ingresados";
      }
    ```

Comentarios extra:

- No uses caracteres como *ñ* para nombres de variables
- No cambies el nombre de clases, por ejemplo usas *MySQLi* cuando el nombre correcto es: [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli) eso en sistemas operativos distintos a Windows te va a dar problemas

**EDICIÓN**

```
include("Conexion.php");

  $objConexion = Conectarse();

  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $clave   = $_POST['password'];


  if (isset($usuario) && !empty($usuario) && isset($clave) && !empty($clave)) {

      $iniciarsesion = $objConexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                              FROM tbl_login_registro 
                                              WHERE Correo_electronico = ? 
                                              AND Contraseña = ?");
      $iniciarsesion->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $clave);
      $iniciarsesion->execute();
      $iniciarsesion->store_result();


      $resultado = $iniciarsesion->num_rows;

      if ($resultado > 0) {
          echo 'El usuario si existe';
      } else {
          echo 'El usuario no existe';
      }
  } else {
      echo "No se pudo iniciar sesión verifica los valores ingresados";
  }
```

**Referencias**

- [num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
- Método [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset)
- [mysqli_store_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.store-result.php)

Comment: Hola BetaM, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, utilice el código que me enviaste pero aun persiste el incidente, ingresos cualquier usuario y clave que no existen en la tabla y el mensaje de respuesta siempre es 'El usuario si existe'.

Comment: Verifica que valores te llegan en ambas variables pues el código te debería funcionar, hazle un echo a cada una y checa que hayas puesto todo tal cual lo escribí

Comment: Hola Beta, verifique que el código que me pasaste estuviera tal cual, pero aun asi si ingreso cualquier dato me dice que si existe inclusive cuando la tabla esta vacía. Le hice un echo a las variables de $usuario y $clave y vienen con los datos que digito en el formulario y tambien le hice un echo a la variable $resultado y siempre viene en uno, así la tabla este vacía, ya no se que hacer la verdad, será un problema con la BD en mysql? gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Más tarde verifico el código