# Contar registros (count) con MySQL y

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Quiero **contar** la cantidad de **registros** que tengo una tabla. Y a su vez esa sumatoria se muestre por pantalla en php.

Acá tengo mi código:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="white-box analytics-info">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Total de Pagos Cerrados</h3>
                            <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                <li>
                                    <div id="sparklinedash3"></div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="text-right"><i class="ti-arrow-up text-info"></i> <span class="counter text-info">AQUÍ QUIERO QUE SE VEA LA CANTIDAD EN NÚMEROS</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

En mi tabla llamada CREADAS tengo una COLUMNA que se llama ESTADO, quiero solo sumar los registros específicos de pagos ACEPTADOS.

entonces he intentado escribir esto pero no se que más hacer:

```
 select count(*) from creadas where estado='Aceptado';
```

¿Pero qué hago para que ese conteo se vea donde les muestro en mi HTML/PHP?

saludos y gracias

************ACTUALIZACIÓN*****************

Me conecto de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
```

session_start();

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pedido');
```

?>

este codigo esta al principio de mi página.

Lo que quiero es que salga la sumatoria acá:

[image: DONDE QUIERO QUE ESTÉ EL CONTADOR]

Y y este es el código de lo que se ve en imagen:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="white-box analytics-info">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Total de Pagos Cerrados</h3>
                        <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                            <li>
                                <div id="sparklinedash3"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-right"><i class="ti-arrow-up text-info"></i> <span class="counter text-info">AQUÍ QUIERO QUE SE VEA LA CANTIDAD EN NÚMEROS</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Donde dice 1 quiero que ahí de mi sumatario de registros

Comment: ¿Qué has tratado con PHP?, por otro lado ¿tratas de únicamente mostrar ese valor ó tu consulta va a traer mas datos y buscas como acomodar esos valores mas el del conteo?

Comment: En php nada, solo esa consulta que ves ahí, no se como traer el dato y mostrarlo en PHP, solo quiero que me cuente la cantidad de registro que tienen el estado=Aceptado, sin son 10 registro que me muestre en un sitio específico 10. El sitio específico lo dejé ahí en mi codigo.

Comment: Necesitamos mas detalles, por ejemplo como te conectas a PHP, considera ampliar con todos los detalles necesarios [ask]

Comment: Para completar tu duda adjunta mas código para poder definir de que forma te conectas, es necesario también saber si lo que deseas crear es un catálogo o sólamente la cantidad de registros.

Comment: Acabo de añadir más información.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta dada [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392108/validaci%c3%b3n-no-verifica-existencia-de-un-usuario-en-la-base-de-datos/392116#392116) tiene mucho de lo que tu ocupas, ya solo quedaría pendiente lo de mostrar en la vista, pero cuando avances mas podemos ir acortando lo que se necesita, checa también los enlaces que dejé en la misma

Comment: Excelente, estoy viendo que es una consulta a la base de datos para un login, es similar a lo que necesito yo en cuanto consulta. Me parece excelente, voy a revisar y comento por acá.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te refires a esto, el código de php debera estar antes para inicializar la variable:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="white-box analytics-info">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Total de Pagos Cerrados</h3>
                        <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                            <li>
                                <div id="sparklinedash3"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-right"><i class="ti-arrow-up text-info"></i> <span class="counter text-info"><?= $resultado ?></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Otra solución seria meter el código HTML en un echo dentro del php.

Para configurar la conexión:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php <--!!aqui esta el codigo de $resultado